# Why does remastersys.com go to some other retailer site?

Tags: discussion

I click a link in another question and it instead went to a retailer site, not a package to remix the system.

This is the post: [Creating a Live CD with Gnome-Classic as default environment?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151456/creating-a-live-cd-with-gnome-classic-as-default-environment)

Comment: That post is from 2012, likely domain was sold.

Comment: Remastersys is now `Remastersys.org`

Comment: question belongs on META. And you edit the question so it is pointing to the correct site :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sold, lapsed or lost in a bet. Whichever way the domain got transferred, the simple fact is that a Chinese chap called Steven currently controls the domain, and therefore they control the content. Steven clearly sees it fit to point it at his generic mass-production tat website.

But for our purposes, this is the same as any link dying off.

- If you can find a replacement (like `remastersys.org`), replace it.
- If you can't, and the post is otherwise good, just "break" the link (with code tags, or whatever) and leave a note about the demise of the domain in the comments.